# Issues of infinity with time ordering of the interaction Hamiltonian of $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, interactions

I use $\phi^4$ theory as an example here, but similar things happen to other theories as well.

In $\phi^4$ theory, we can easily use the Lagrangian [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field_theory#%CF%864_theory) to write down the interaction Hamiltonian (in interaction picture, canonical quantization):
$$
H_I=\frac{g}{4!}\int d^3 x \phi(x)^4,
$$
**My first question:** must I impose normal ordering on $H_I$ and write down
$$
H_I=\frac{g}{4!}\int d^3 x :\phi(x)^4:
$$
instead? I have seen at different places the interaction Hamiltonian written without the normal ordering colons $::$, and I am confused by this. Does that mean normal ordering can be implied implicitly? After all, the Hamiltonian of free theory without interaction is normal ordered.

**The reason why I think we should have normal ordering is this:** to compute the scattering amplitude, we use Wick's theorem, and express time ordering in terms of normal orderings. If we write out the first order term of the S-matrix (in Dyson series):
$$
S-\text{Id} \sim \frac{-ig}{4!} \mathcal T \int d^4 x \phi(x)^4, 
$$
we see that we are time ordering ($\mathcal T$) four operators that are at the same time and same place:
$$
\mathcal T (\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x))
$$
Of course, now the time are all the same, so it makes little sense to order this in time. But I include $\mathcal T$ here anyway because we are going to apply wick's theorem:
$$ 
\mathcal T (\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\phi_3(x_3)\phi_4(x_4))=:\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\phi_3(x_3)\phi_4(x_4): + \text{contraction}(\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)):\phi_3(x_3)\phi_4(x_4): \\+ \text{all other contractions}
$$
Applying this formula to $\mathcal T (\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x))$ means that we are expressing $\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)$ in terms of its normal orderings. But the Feynman propagator $\text{contraction}(\phi(x)\phi(x))=\Delta_F(0)\sim \delta(0)=\infty$, so if $\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)$ is NOT **treated** as normal ordered, then the extra contraction terms will ALL be infinite. So we need to ignore all these terms to give a useful scattering amplitude.

In short, it seems that in a theory with two fields $\phi_1, \phi_2$, we should treat all fields *at the same point in the spacetime* **as if they are already normal ordered**, or in other words, stipulate that their contraction $\text{contraction}(\phi_1(x)\phi_2(x))$ is ZERO.

**Is my summary accurate?**

Comment: relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305051/84967